# What is this building?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture

[image]

What and where is this building? It's a stock photo and no amount of reverse-image searching on Google has provided me with a relevant result.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please edit and add where you found the photo. It may help in identifying it.

Comment: Seems to be from a guy called Has Bonk: [here](http://hasbonk.tumblr.com/) and [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/17061739/Projekt-Katze) and [here](https://unsplash.com/@hasbonk?grid=multi)

Comment: @mts my search led me to the same, and the tags there helped me :)

Comment: It was a stock-photo on a free built-in Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's the [Palau de les Arts Reina Sofia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palau_de_les_Arts_Reina_Sofia). It's an opera house and cultural centre in Valencia, Spain.

[image]
Photo from [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palau_de_les_Arts_Reina_Sofia#/media/File:El_Palau_de_les_Arts_Reina_Sof%C3%ADa,_Valencia_-_Jan_2007.jpg).

Comment: That's a Calatrava right?  He's unique.